# Maven plugin for checking coding conventions during build

Tags: java, maven

we are a team of developers with very different experiences and coding styles. But as we are working on same projects it is necessary to have some common ground regarding code style.
Is there a maven plugin that can check for several coding rules? We already use checkstyle and spotbugs, but I'm interested if it's possible to include it in regular build.
I'd like to know if it's possible to make build fail (or at least give a severe warning) when certain coding rules are not fullfilled.

I thought about programming something by myself but would like to know if there is already a plugin that does what we want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html)
to verify coding styles and to set style do you want, and other configuration

example:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
     <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
     <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
     <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>validate</id>
       <phase>validate</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>check</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to maven but you can use sonar.

Comment: SonarQube is about static code analysis not about style like formatting ...